# proof function g is zero if integral of g*v is zero

Tags: calculus

I am trying to show the following statement.
Let $\Omega\subset\ R^d$ be an open set and let $g\in\ C(\Omega)$ be such that, for every $v\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ with $v=0$ on the boundary of $\Omega$, we have that $\int _{\Omega}g(x)v(x)dx=0$.

Show that $g=0$.

I tried to prove this statement by contradiction. Therefore, I assumed that $g$ is unequal to zero.
Since g is a continious function, there exists a point $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that $g(x_0)>0$ (w.l.o.g. I assumed $g(x_0)>0$ because the proof for  $g(x_0)<0$ would be the same).
g is continious, hence there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $g(x)>0$ for all x in $U$.
Let $K$ be the closure of $U$.
Now define the function $v:\Omega \to R$ as
\begin{equation}
v(x)= 1\ if\ x\ \in K\ and\ v(x)=0\ if\ x\ \notin K
\end{equation}
v is a continious function in $\Omega$ because K is a closed set. In addition, v is zero at the boundary of $\Omega$.

$\int _{\Omega}g(x)v(x)dx=\int _{K}g(x)v(x)dx=\int _{K}g(x)dx>0$. The inequality holds because $g(x)>0\ \forall x\in U$.
This contradicts with our assumption that the integral $\int _{\Omega}g(x)v(x)dx$ is zero for all $v$. Thus, $g=0$.
Is this proof correct or are there any mistakes? Thank you!

Comment: $v$ looks very discontinuous.

Comment: Could you help me to fix my proof?

Comment: If you're taking a course in which such an exercise was assigned, surely you have learned some important techniques and constructions. Look through your notes and book.